# Pandas: Select rows whose dictionary contains a specific key

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, dataframe

I have a dataframe, in which one column is all dictionary. I want to select rows whose dictionary contains a given key.

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1,2,3], "B": [{"a":1}, {"b":2}, {"c":3}]})
>>> df
   A         B
0  1  {'a': 1}
1  2  {'b': 2}
2  3  {'c': 3}
>>> df['b' in df['B']]  
# the desired result is the row with index 1. But this causes an error: KeyError: False
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is one way:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1,2,3], "B": [{"a":1}, {"b":2}, {"c":3}]})

df = df[df['B'].map(lambda x: 'b' in x)]

#    A         B
# 1  2  {'b': 2}
```

**Explanation**

- `pd.Series.map` accepts anonymous (`lambda`) functions as an argument.
- The function takes each element of `B` and checks whether `b` is in that element, returning a Boolean series.
- We use the natural Boolean indexing of `df[bool_series]` to choose the required rows.

Comment: This opens up a whole new horizon of possibilities with pandas.

Answer (score 0):

Using get the dict keys

```
df.B.apply(lambda x : 'b' in x.keys())
Out[89]: 
0    False
1     True
2    False
Name: B, dtype: bool
```